# Получить домен из URL

Tags: php

Допустим есть ссылки вида:

```
http://site.ru/news/
https://site.ru/news/
https://domen.site.ru/
```

На выходе должно вывести:

```
site.ru
site.ru
domen.site.ru
```

Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Регуляркой или [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php). Пожалуйста

Comment: Как именно? Для чего этот сайт по вашему тут?

Comment: Тут Помощь,а не сделайте за меня

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - "Сначала опишите проблему, потом **добавьте код**. Сначала более подробно опишите проблему, которую вы сформулировали в заголовке. Поясните, **как вы столкнулись с проблемой и что препятствует её решению**"

Comment: `parse_url()` вам в помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
echo $parse['host']; // prints 'google.com'
```

Comment: можно сразу с параметром `PHP_URL_HOST` вызвать